# generate_series function in Hibernate

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, hql, nativequery

I have a column `total` in the table `Inv` and I want to extract total amount per month in hibernate using `generate_series`:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT _month," +
            "sum(inv.total) AS total" +
            "FROM FUNCTION('generate_series', 1, 12, 1) as _month" +
            "join InvSC as sc on FUNCTION('extract', month, sc.timestamp) = _month" +
            "JOIN Inv as inv on sc.invoiceNumber = inv.invoiceNumber" +
            "GROUP BY _month")
    List<String> totalAmount();
```

I have syntax error

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.query.sqm.ParsingException: line 1:58 mismatched input 'FUNCTION' expecting {<EOF>, ',', FROM, GROUP, ORDER, WHERE}
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.StandardHqlTranslator$1.syntaxError(StandardHqlTranslator.java:46) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
```

How can I write the query using `FROM (FUNCTION ('generate_series'))`?

Answer (score 1):

Since [Hibernate 6.2 introduced support of common table expressions](https://in.relation.to/2023/02/20/hibernate-orm-62-ctes/), I believe, you can call table functions using following approach:

I. create dummy table with single row and corresponding dummy entity

```sql
create table dual(dummy varchar(1));
insert into dual(dummy) values('x');
```

```java
@Entity(name = "dual")
@Table(name = "dual")
public class Dual {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "dummy")
    protected String dummy;
    
}
```

II. Now, you are able to write something like in JPQL:

```java
WITH mon AS MATERIALIZED (
   SELECT FUNCTION('generate_series', 1, 12, 1) AS month_ FROM dual
)
SELECT mon.month_, sum(inv.total) AS total
FROM mon, InvSC as sc, Inv as inv
WHERE sc.invoiceNumber = inv.invoiceNumber
AND mon.month_ = FUNCTION('extract', 'month', sc.timestamp)
GROUP BY mon.month_
```

Comment: Is it possible to achieve the same functionality using HQL?

Comment: @Programmer2B have you tried what I have suggested?

Comment: Yes, it works with a materialized view. I was just wondering whether is it possible to do it using HQL with @Query annotation without creating a new Entity.

Comment: That is HQL syntax